# Facebook Login via App Engine

Tags: android, facebook, google-app-engine

I have an Android client that connectes to an App Engine server via Restlet. I would to incorporate a Facebook login to my application, by dispatching a login request to Facebook from the App Engine server after the client initially requests to login.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You'd be best off using an [existing java library for web authentication](https://github.com/leleuj/pac4j) (works with OAuth, OpenID and of course supports Facebook).